# Como pongo una imagen de fondo en tkinter con python?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Tengo un codigo para entrar automaticamente a mis clases en linea pero quiero agregarle un a imagen de fondo al programa pero no se como, he intentado mucghas cosas pero ninguna me funciona, me pone "no such file or directory" pero está en la misma ruta. aqui esta el codigo de la interfaz, solo quiero agregarle una foto que se llama "ojo.jpg"

```
window= Tk()
window.title("Entrador jaja")
window.geometry("500x300")
window.resizable(0,0)
btnEsp=Button(window, bg="white", text="Español", width=20,command=Espanol)
btnEsp.grid(column=3, row=1)
btnMat=Button(window, bg="white", text="Matemáticas", width=20, command=Mate)
btnMat.grid(column=3, row=2)
btnEngl=Button(window, bg="white", text="Inglés", width=20, command=InglesNV)
btnEngl.grid(column=3, row=3)
btnArt=Button(window, bg="white", text="Artes", width=20, command=Artes)
btnArt.grid(column=3, row=4)
btnComp=Button(window, bg="white", text="Computación", width=20, command=Computacion)
btnComp.grid(column=3, row=5)
btnInv=Button(window, bg="white", text="Investigadores", width=20, command=Investigadores)
btnInv.grid(column=3, row=6)
btnTut=Button(window, bg="white", text="Tutoría", width=20, command=Tutoria)
btnTut.grid(column=3, row=7)
btnFCE=Button(window, bg="white", text="Civica", width=20, command=FCE)
btnFCE.grid(column=3, row=8)
btnHist=Button(window, bg="white", text="Historia", width=20, command=Historia)
btnHist.grid(column=3, row=9)
btnFis=Button(window, bg="white", text="Fisica", width=20, command=fisica)
btnFis.grid(column=3, row=10)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: importa PIL para cambiar de tamaño la imagen

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar `PhotoImage` para, por así decirlo, leer la imagen, y luego `Label` para el widget. Te explico en comentarios con un código básico de ejemplo lo que he hecho y su resultado.

**Código**:

```
from tkinter import Tk, PhotoImage, Label
# from tkinter import PhotoImage

app = Tk()
app.title("Hola S.O")

# Lees la imagen:
# He colocado ruta relativa, es decir, la imagen a la misma 
# altura de la aplicación. Si prefieres, puedes colocar una
# ruta absoluta.
imagen = PhotoImage(file = "ejemplo.png")

# Con Label y la opción image, puedes mostrar una imagen en el widget:
background = Label(image = imagen, text = "Imagen S.O de fondo")

# Con place puedes organizar el widget de la imagen posicionandolo
# donde lo necesites (relwidth y relheight son alto y ancho en píxeles):
background.place(x = 0, y = 0, relwidth = 1, relheight = 1)

# Por defecto el fondo es blaco. Accediendo al método config
# de Label podrías, por ejemplo, establecer un color de fondo distinto:
# background.config(bg = "gray")

app.mainloop()
```

**Resultado**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te dejo documentación (de esta forma puedes aprender un poco más y gestionarlo como te sea mejor) de:

- Widget  [Label](https://unipython.com/tkinter-label-entry-metodos-place-y-grid/)
- Método [place](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_place.htm) de `Label`.
- [PhotoImage](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm)

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: lo probaré, muchas gracias

Comment: _tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file, no me deja, dice que no reconoció información y la foto esta en la mimsa ruta, que hago?

Answer (score 1):

con PhotoImage lo puedes hacer y meterlo en un Label
En mi caso no hizo falta importar ya que todo viene en el primer import
(Probado con un archivo .gif

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

imagen= PhotoImage(file="imagen.gif")

Label(root, image=imagen, bd=0).pack()

root.mainloop()
```